# require parent directive's controller, when parent directive is not known

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a grid system in Angular.js, that looks like the following:

```
<grid>
  <data-row>
    <cell>
    </cell>
  </data-row>

  ....

  <group-row>
    <cell>
    </cell>
  </group-row>
</grid>
```

I need to reach the row's controller inside the cells, but as you can see, there are multiple kinds of rows, so I can not write this inside the cell directive:

```
return {
  ...
  require: '^row'
}
```

Can you suggest some kind of solution to be able to reference to a general parent directive's controller?

Comment: Can you copy your code in a jsfiddle ? You could benefit from the controllerAs attribute, but it depends on your architecture.

Comment: Checkout the question [Using multiple directives in require with Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506827/using-multiple-directives-in-require-with-angularjs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, two options.

1) Have a single `row` element directive which you then decorate with a `row-type` attribute directives. You'd then be `require`ing the row into both your cells and into your row-type decorators.

```
<grid>
  <row row-type="data">
    <cell>
    </cell>
  </row>

  ....

  <row row-type="group">
    <cell>
    </cell>
  </row>
</grid>
```

2) Have your cell directive require multiple optional parents -

```
return {
   ...
   require: ["?data-row", "?group-row"],
   ...
}
```

And handle your different logics in your cell's linking function based on the presence or absence of one or the other. That feels a little dirtier to me, but could work for what you need.